# Why do we pass a function as a parameter in python

Tags: python-3.x

I understand the process of passing the function as a parameter to a different function but, coming from the c# background, I don't understand the need of it.

Can someone please make me aware of some scenarios in which this is preferred?

Comment: You want an example code?

Comment: no, i want the uses of passing function as a parameter like when do i need to use it

Comment: Working on an answer for you.\

Comment: Look at decorators and async code. A simple example would be a function that times another function and then prints the runtime of the function passed to it. This is a classic use of a decorator.

Comment: Take note that C# also supports higher-order functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function#C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing functions into functions allows to parameterise *behaviour*. This is not unlike passing values into functions allows to parameterise *data*.

```
def is_greater(what: int, base: int):
    if what > base:  # fixed behaviour, parameterised data
       print(f'{what} is greater')

def is_valid(what: int, condition: 'Callable'):
    if condition(what):  # parameterised behaviour
       print(f'{what} is valid')
```

---

Some common use-cases include:

- `map`, `filter` and others that apply *some behaviour* to iterables. The functions itself merely implement the "apply to each element" part, but the behaviour can be swapped out:

  ```
  >>> print(*map(float, ['1', '2', '3.0'])
  1.0 2.0 3.0
  ```

  In such situations, one often uses a `lambda` to define the behaviour on the fly.

  ```
  >>> print(sorted(
  ...     ['Bobby Tables', 'Brian Wayne', 'Charles Chapeau'],
  ...     key=lambda name: name.split()[1]),  # sort by last name
  ... )
  ['Charles Chapeau', 'Bobby Tables', 'Brian Wayne']
  ```
- Function decorators that wrap a function with additional behaviour.

  ```
  def print_call(func):
      """Decorator that prints the arguments its target is called with"""
      def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
          print(f'call {func} with {args} and {kwargs}')
          return func(*args, **kwargs)
      return wrapped_func

  @print_call
  def rolling_sum(*numbers, initial=0):
      totals = [initial]
      for number in numbers:
          totals.append(totals[-1] + number)
      return totals

  rolling_sum(1, 10, 27, 42, 5, initial=100)
  # call <function rolling_sum at 0x10ed6fd08> with ([1, 10, 27, 42, 5],) and {'initial': 100}
  ```

  Every time you see a decorator applied with `@` it is a higher order function.
- Callbacks and payloads that are executed at another time, context, condition, thread or even process.

  ```
  def call_after(delay: float, func: 'Callable', *args, **kwargs):
      """Call ``func(*args, **kwargs)`` after ``delay`` seconds"""
      time.sleep(delay)
      func(*args, **kwargs)

  thread = threading.Thread(
      target=call_after,  # payload for the thread is a function
      args=(1, print, 'Hello World'))
  thread.start()
  print("Let's see what happens...")
  # Let's see what happens...
  # 
  # Hello World
  ```
- Passing functions instead of values allows to emulate [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).

  ```
  def as_needed(expensive_computation, default):
      if random_condition():
         return expensive_computation()
      return default
  ```

Answer (score 4):

One of the reasons why passing a function as a parameter is useful is the [concept of lambda functions in python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp).

```
method2(lambda: method1('world'))
>>> hello world
```

The benefit of ***lambda*** functions are easily visible when used with python functions `map()`, `filter()`, and `reduce()`.

**Lambda functions with `map()`**

```
>map(lambda x: x*2, my_list)
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38]
```

**Lambda with `reduce()`**

```
>reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, my_list)
190
```

**Lambda with `filter()`**

```
filter(lambda x: x >10, my_list)
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Basically unlike `c#` your *code gets reduced number of lines* and *becomes more efficient
since your function call and execution happens on the same line*